# htaccess 301 redircect all URLS that begin with certain text

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have thousands of old URLS that look like below and what I was wondering if there was a way to redirect all URLS that begin with index2.php? to one page, rather than doing them all separately

I was able to redirect all other URLS on the site buy using

```
RewriteRule ^/old-category(.*)$ /index.php? [L,R=301]
```

but this only works when there is a directory in the URL which these don't have.

These are typical URLS

- `index2.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=&category_id=2&page=shop.browse&pop=1&tmpl=component`
- `index2.php?page=shop.product_details&product_id=18&flypage=flypage_rhino.tpl&pop=1&manufacturer_id=1&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=7`
- `index2.php?page=shop.product_details&product_id=34&flypage=flypage_rhino.tpl&pop=1&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=7`
- `index2.php?page=shop.product_details&product_id=121&flypage=flypage_rhino.tpl&pop=1&manufacturer_id=1&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=7`
- `index2.php?page=shop.product_details&product_id=9&flypage=flypage.tpl&pop=1&manufacturer_id=1&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=7`
- `index2.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage_rhino.tpl&product_id=85&category_id=16&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=7&pop=1&tmpl=component`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the same thing:

```
RewriteRule ^/?index2\.php$ /index.php? [L,R=301]
```

instead of `old-category`, replace it with `index2\.php`.

Comment: I tried this earlier but with no success but I had not added the \ before the dot and that fixed it